# How can I show a custom map in Android?

Tags: android, geoserver, custom-view, wms, indoor-positioning-system

I'm new using maps on Android, as a custom map I mean a map built by my own Server of Maps (I'm using GeoServer with WMS) Should I create a custom view or can I use a MapFragment?
Or any library that I can use for this? (My custom maps are for indoor location)

Comment: You can implement your own [TileProvider within google maps api v2](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileProvider)

Comment: Sorry for asking, but how should I do that? Do you have any example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Osmdroid](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) to display your own map tiles. The implementation looks something like this:

```
public void addTiledMaplayer(){
        final MapTileProviderBasic tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext());
        final ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource(layerName, null, 15, 16, 256, ".png",
            "http://url.with/tiles/");
        tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
        final TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(tileProvider, this.getBaseContext());
        tilesOverlay.setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        map.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
        map.invalidate();

    }
```

If you do not have usable tiles, you can extract them from your Geoserver using a program called Mobile Atlas Creator.